# Can't import holoviews as hv

Tags: python, python-3.x, holoviews

I am trying to run holoviews, but I keep getting an error. Here is my test code.

```
import holoviews as hv

hv.extension("bokeh")
```

When I run that script, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-22faa9093b59> in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 import holoviews as hv
      8 import plotly.graph_objects as go
      9 import plotly.express as pex

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\__init__.py in <module>
     10 
     11 from . import util                                       # noqa (API import)
---> 12 from .annotators import annotate                         # noqa (API import)
     13 from .core import archive, config                        # noqa (API import)
     14 from .core.boundingregion import BoundingBox             # noqa (API import)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\annotators.py in <module>
      8 import param
      9 
---> 10 from panel.pane import PaneBase
     11 from panel.layout import Row, Tabs
     12 from panel.util import param_name

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from . import layout # noqa
      2 from . import links # noqa
      3 from . import pane # noqa
      4 from . import param # noqa
      5 from . import pipeline # noqa

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\__init__.py in <module>
----> 1 from .accordion import Accordion # noqa
      2 from .base import Column, ListLike, ListPanel, Panel, Row, WidgetBox # noqa
      3 from .card import Card # noqa
      4 from .flex import FlexBox # noqa
      5 from .grid import GridBox, GridSpec # noqa

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\accordion.py in <module>
      1 import param
      2 
----> 3 from bokeh.models import Column as BkColumn, CustomJS
      4 
      5 from .base import NamedListPanel

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.models'
```

I tried this: `conda upgrade bokeh`

The upgrade seems to finish off fine, but I got that same error again. Any thoughts on how I can get holoviews to run?

BTW, this exact same process works perfectly fine on my work machine, it just doesn't work on my personal laptop. Maybe there's some kind of package naming conflict, not sure.

Comment: make sure you're using the same channels and solving the dependencies *together*. `conda create -c conda-forge -n hv holoviews boken scikit-learn` creates an env where this code runs straight through for me. Also... I assume your MRE is just `import holoveiws as hv; hv.extension('bokeh')`, and while sankey diagrams are your end goal, they have nothing to do with this question?

Comment: do you have a file/directory/module in your current working dir called "bokeh"? please include the full stacktrace.

Comment: I tried what you suggested; still getting the same result. Also, posted the full stack trace.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: ok - a valid reason for closing a question is "not reproducible" and since you've already said this works just fine on your work machine we're going to need a lot more debugging detail about what's not working on your personal machine for this to not be closed. OS, python installation, exact commands to reproduce the environment & error. make sure you're working in a completely clean directory and execute only the lines in this script. try running this in a python terminal with no files present, etc.

Comment: I would guess that "import bokeh" in the same environment will also fail; it doesn't seem like a problem to do with your holoviews installation. E.g. does ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh exist?

Comment: I do have this: C:\Users\ryans\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\bokeh

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it by installing an older version of channels:

```
pip install channels==3.0.5
```

Hopefully a newer version will not have this dependency issue.